# How to configure "Maximum concurrency" for AWS SQS in aws_lambda_event_source_mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs

In Terraform, how can I set the maximum concurrency for an `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping` using SQS?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the max concurrency?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear that `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping` should be used?

Answer (score 4):

Terraform supports a configuration block named [scaling_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping.html#scaling_config-configuration-block) from aws_lambda_event_source_mapping, inside this block you can use the argument **maximum_concurrency**

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "lambda_trigger" {

  event_source_arn  = "your arn"
  function_name     = "your lambda function arn"
  batch_size = 10
  scaling_config {
      maximum_concurrency = 50
  }
}
```